# Filter questions by favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

We can currently save favorite tags, which seems to highlight questions in the list, and give a quick shortcut to filter all questions by only that tag.

But is there a way to in one or two clicks filter the questions by all favorite tags? I think there should be, would be useful.

**Edit:** This question is now obsolete with the new site layout. Just save your favorite tags as a new menu tab.

Comment: You can search by multiple tags in the search box by typing `[tag1][tag2]`. For example, a search for 2 of my fave tags would be  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+pivot, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but a shortcut to search for all favorite tags, instead of just one at a time.  The title "Favorite tags" itself could be a link to filter for all favorites.

Comment: MSE duplicate [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags).

Comment: See request here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Comment: Could you point out how to "save your favorite tags as a new menu tab"? Very nice to see that you've figured that out, I was going to ask the same question. I have been searching for some time but for now.. got no idea.

Comment: Click Questions, you will see the tabs: home, voted, active, newest, new tab+

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just use the favorites in my browser.  For example, when I want to look at iOS questions, the link I use is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios+or+objective-c+or+xcode+or+iphone+or+cocoa_touch+or+uitableview+or+ipad+or+nsstring+or+ios6+or+uitableviewcell+or+uilabel+or+nsmutablearray+or+nsarray+or+uiview?sort=newest&pagesize=30
```

Basically, you just chain all of the tags together with `+or+`

Comment: How would the syntax for the URL be if you wanted something like `tagA or (tagB and tagC)` or `tagA and not tagB` ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've only used `+or+` to filter tags, so I don't know. Might be worth a new question.

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing this answer, there is a two-click solution, starting at the favorite tags listing in the right column on the front page:

1. Click on ("Favorite Tags" ->) "edit"
2. Click on "advanced tag subscriptions"

Comment: this just takes me to the filters page -- I don't see a `favorite tags` filter there.  What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't do anything specific. For me, if I click on "advanced tag subscriptions", the URL [https://stackexchange.com/filters/151146/favorite-tags](https://stackexchange.com/filters/151146/favorite-tags) is opened. So yes, it is the filters page but it seems that a "favorite tags" filter is pre-selected.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `Manage filtered questions emails` feature in via preferences. It allows you to create custom filters, but there is also default Favorite Tags filter, which I think displays all questions matching favorite tags.

Answer (score -2):

One useful approach I've realized, is to instead filter out everything you DON'T want to see. Just keep adding items to your ignored tags list until the list of questions is just things you want.

Comment: doesn't help me see everything tagged `foo` -- if I exclude `bar` I won't see Qs tagged both `foo` **and** `bar`, right?