# Is it possible to create a tab with just *my* tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I created a list of favorite tags on Stack Overflow. I would like to filter the questions that only have one or more of my tags. I remember there was an option like that before ("+ new tab"), but it had a bug that the tags were connected by and and not or. And with the new (old?) UI this is gone altogether.

Can I not find it or is it indeed gone? If gone, is it coming back?

Comment: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256411/8517948)'s an alternative

Comment: The [interesting tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) pretty much already does that, doesn't it?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - no, not really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copied from [Filter questions by favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256394/filter-questions-by-favorite-tags/273063#273063)

1. Click on ("Favorite Tags" ->) "edit"
2. Click on "advanced tag subscriptions"